# aws sqs lambda: messages not re-appearing

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I have followed standard aws lambda creation with sqs trigger.
Then I sent message to sqs queue which then kicks lambda, which in turn writes to stdout. All good.

The issue is: I have not yet deleted receipt of the message and I expect the message to appear again for processing after the visibility period of 60 seconds(default). This is not happening, wonder why.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func handler(ctx context.Context, sqsEvent events.SQSEvent) error {

    for _, message := range sqsEvent.Records {
        fmt.Println("Id", message.MessageId)
        fmt.Println("Source", message.EventSource)
        fmt.Println("Body", message.Body)
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handler)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, are you waiting for the same message that triggered the lambda to trigger the lambda again?

Comment: Yes. I am assuming that if lambda fails to process a message, then that message should reappear for re-processing as I haven't yet deleted it. Is it how it supposed to work or not ?!

Comment: But your lambda isn't failing at processing the message. If you want it to fail you can either call `panic` or return an error from your handler (`nil` means all went good)

Comment: Oh I see, let me try that!

Comment: You were right, thank you, 2 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Making an answer out of the conversation with the OP**

**Question**: Op wants to check how SQS retries sending events to lambda when events fail. Op provides the code for a lambda function written in Go

**Problem**: Provided lambda does not fail so no retry behavior happens.

**Solution**: Rewrite lambda so it always fail.

```
    func handler(ctx context.Context, sqsEvent events.SQSEvent) error {

    for _, message := range sqsEvent.Records {
        fmt.Println("Id", message.MessageId)
        fmt.Println("Source", message.EventSource)
        fmt.Println("Body", message.Body)
    }

    return error.New("Song by B.S.")
    }
```

Comment: but won't this cause lambda function to retry again ?

Comment: I think OP was just experimenting/learning with lambdas using SQS trigger otherwise it wouldn't be practical to write a function as such

Answer (score 1):

By default if your lambda succeeds it will automatically delete the message from the queue. If you want to keep the message in the queue, you would have to explicitly fail the lambda using the callback and an error or context.fail